# file reading with mpi

Tags: filesystems, mpi

I want several mpi processes to read the same file, I googled for it and found that it can be done through MPI IO but only in GPFS or HPSS filesystems. Is there a way to do it in ext4?

Comment: Where did you find this information?

Comment: http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/B673/node179.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document you are referring to is a scientific programming course at a university, and they are referring to their own, university-internal architecture. MPI file operations are independent of the underlying file system, which is the responsibility of the operating system.

You can find university-unrelated information about MPI file operations e.g. [here](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_File_iwrite.3.php) or [here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_File_iwrite.html), but especially Chapter 13 of the [MPI 2.2 Standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf) which exclusively deals with I/O.